# How to hook every app？and make an uiwindow

Tags: ios, iphone, hook, jailbreak, theos

**What i need：**

I want make an hidden UIWindow above every app except springboard.The window's orientation is equal to the most front app.

**What i have done before:**

I hook springboard,and make an UIWindow,but the window's orientation is equal to the springboard and I can't transform the springboard.

**My question**

So,can i hook every app and make an UIWindow the window's orientation equal to the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something general for your bundle filter.
Examples :com.apple.UIKit
com.apple.Foundation

Cheers